# No such module Almofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

I downloaded Alamofire and added Alamofire.xcodeproj to my project. Then I added it to Embedded libraries and built phase target dependencies. Everything looks ok but it gives me Alamofire module error on Import Alamofire.

I am using Swift 2.0, just FYI. What am I missing?

Thanks for your help in advance,

Comment: try adding Alamofire using CocoaPods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.

For Swift 2.0 there is no need to add Alamofire.xcodeproj into your xcode. Simply copy and paste source folder from https://github.com/Alamofire and you are done.

Comment: This no longer works.  Using alamofire 3.1.5 and Xcode 7.2

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve ths issue by upgrating it to latest XCODE.

Answer (score -1):

Try this link.

i recently fixed this issue in my project. and this code is working good.
please try this link : http://www.programminghub.us/2017/12/no-such-module-almofire.html

```
    import Alamofire

    let urlString = "" //your url
    Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: 
    ["": ""],
    encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: ["": ""]).responseJSON {
    response in
          print(response)
          switch response.result {
          case .success:
               print(response.value!)
               break
          case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
          }
    }
```